# How to install Python script on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a small command-line utility in Python. I also created setup.py script:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'name': 'clitool',
    'author': 'aa',
    'author_email': 'ww',
    'version': '1.0-rc',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': [],
    'scripts': ['clitool']
}

setup(**config)
```

When I call:

```
setup.py install
```

my script copied to `C:\Python34\Scripts` path. This path is in the PATH variable, but Windows when I try to start my clitool from some direcory writes:

```
"clitool" not recognized as an internal or external command
```

It's possible to run from any directory, only the files from `C:\Python34\Scripts` with the exe extension.
But my script is copied as a file without extension and in Windows it does not run it.

Comment: Are you running this from Windows Explorer or cmd.exe?  Have you tried `clitool.py`?  It should have a `.py` extension (although there are others)

Comment: @cdarke, `clitool.py` is works, but I wanted to write so that the utility can be called without .py extension

Comment: Why?  On Windows (unlike UNIX/Linux/OS X) the shell (Windows Explorer, cmd.exe, powershell) cannot tell which type a file is unless you set its file extension.  The shell uses that as a lookup into the Windows registry to discover which program should be run.  There is  a default, but you would have to write a `.cmd` file to run your python.  Is that what you want?

Comment: No, I wanted to understand how utilities like `django-admin` works

Comment: The entry_points example in [this link](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/command-line-scripts.html) may work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'name': 'clitool',
    'author': 'aa',
    'author_email': 'ww',
    'version': '1.0-rc',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': [],    
    'entry_points' : {
        'console_scripts': ['clitool=clitool.cli:main'],
    }
}

setup(**config)
```